# What happens first: onCreate or configureFlutterEngine?

Tags: java, android, flutter

I need to know which one of these happens first:

`onCreate` or `configureFlutterEngine`?

I'm in

```
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
    }
}
```

and I need to be certain of which one is called first. I must know it for sure, not simply print and see.

Comment: Write Log("abc","1") in onCreate and Log("abc","2") in configureFlutterEngine. You will simply see in logcat which one execute first.

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin I know, but this is not a guarantee that they always happen in the same order

Comment: Maybe you use for example Firebase read data in one function, so that another will execute sooner. But generally they have specific order for running.

Comment: Do you get your desired response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- onCreate first
- about configureFlutterEngine see

https://api.flutter.dev/javadoc/io/flutter/embedding/android/FlutterActivity.html

> public void **configureFlutterEngine**(@NonNull FlutterEngine
>   flutterEngine)
>
> Hook for subclasses to easily configure a FlutterEngine, e.g., register > plugins.
>
> This method is called after provideFlutterEngine(Context).